# Tapping on username while commenting after @ symbol with a high probability leads to invalid system response on touch screen devices

Tags: bug, comments, display-names, accessibility, touch-screen

It's very hard to correctly select user name while commenting on mobile devices. Even when tap is marked inside the tooltip with username, as the result system decided that I tapped on the link from previous comment and redirects me to profile page. Please look at animation below:

> [image]

If you look closely you will see that the tap center is located clearly on tooltip and expected obvious behavior is to add name to the comment (light blue circle is the tap position provided from native Android screen recorder tool):

> [image]

There's a lot of similar situations, when instead of selecting username I can finish with the actions on last posted comment:

- flag it (when flag icon is near to tap area)

> [image]

- focus on it (when timestamp/link is near to tap area)

And so on.

Comment: I don't consider it a bug. If you have a better suggestion, please suggest it as feature request. For example, navigate between the auto complete suggestions with arrow keys (up/down) instead or in addition to TAB key, as mobile devices often don't have that key indeed.

Comment: This is so annoying. The tooltip should be over the input box below the text I’m typing so if I do miss it it doesn’t do anything except maybe move my cursor. The UX for SE on a touch device is straight up awful.

Comment: @ShadowWizard from my PoV it's **definetely** a bug since if you look closely you will see that the [tap center is located clearly on tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHTBz.jpg) and expected obvious behavior is to add name to the comment.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ All this time I thought it was my fat fingers - thanks for pointing out the tap is on the tooltip.